# Laravel 5.5 Collective checkbox

Tags: checkbox, laravel-5.5

Então amigos tudo bem com vocês, estou iniciando em Laravel e não estou conseguindo resolver um problema que deve ser simples.

Tenho uma `view` que insere dados no `db` com um formulário construído através do `collective` e um checkbox único que salva 0 ou 1 no campo.

Até ai tudo bem, gravando corretamente. Porem quando uso o mesmo formulário para edição dos registros, se eu setar qualquer valor no checkbox na hora de atualizar os dados ele salva oque esta no value `` definido no `collective`  no caso dentro do segundo parâmetro `$pessoa->cliente`, dentro da minha `view` eu tendo uma função javascript que quando marco ou desmarco o checkbox ele altera o `value` no formulario.
pelos testes que realizei aqui ele tem salvado a informação do value que defino dentro do `collective` e como se ele não considerasse o value do checkbox definido no javascript e só oque eu definir como value no `collective`.

se eu definir o formulario da seguinte forma:
`{!! Form::label('cliente', 'Cliente') !!}
  {!! Form::checkbox('cliente', 'teste' , null, ['onclick' => 'myFunction()'']) !!}`

ele salva teste mesmo que la no navegador quando clico no checkbox ele defini outro valor par o mesmo ...
Peço desculpas é espero que tenha sido mais claro dessa vez.

Segue o método do  `Controller`.

```
public function atualizar($id, Request $request){
   $pessoa = Pessoa::findOrfail($id);
   $pessoa = $pessoa->update($request->all());
   return Redirect::to('pessoas/' . $id . '/editar');
   \Session::flash('mensagem_sucesso_atu', 'Atualizado com sucesso!');
}
```

Segue o trecho da `view`:

```
{!! Form::label('cliente', 'Cliente') !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('cliente', $pessoa->cliente , null, ['onclick' => 'myFunction()','div' => 'cliente']) !!}
```

Comment: Está confuso sua duvida? poderia melhorar

Comment: Deixa eu tenta resumir usando criador de formulario pra criar o checkbox
{!! Form::checkbox('cliente', '',null, ['onclick' => 'myFunction()','div' => 'cliente']) !!}

ele salva oque tiver definido no segundo parametro  que no exemplo acima esta vazio '', na minha view de edição eu preciso trazer o valor no checkbox, alguma coisa assim $pessoa->id porem quando chamo o metodo de atualizar os dados ele não saval oque esta definido no meu "html"  qaundo inspeciono o elemento .. ele salvar oque esta definido no parametro valor nesse no caso do exemplo acima vazio ''

Comment: Tem que colocar os controllers o model e a sua View na pergunta é explicar em cima disso.

Comment: Veja se melhorou agora

Answer (score 0):

Então pra quem tiver o mesmo problema na hora de realizar atualização no banco de dados no caso com formulários que checkbox desmarcados tenham que salvar alguma informação a solução e muito simples perdi horas com java script quando a solução esta dentro do próprio `collective`, é somente inserir um `hidden` com o mesmo nome do checkbox e colocar o valor zero, como checkbox 'desmarcado' traz um `null` você define que caso ele esteja desmarcado o valor dele é 0, foi exatamente oque tentei fazer com javascript mais por algum motivo não gravava no banco mais segue como eu resolvi...

`{{Form::hidden('cliente',0)}}
 {!! Form::checkbox('cliente') !!}`

Claro que não descobrir sozinho achei nesse site outro forum 
https://laravel.io/forum/09-26-2014-handling-unchecked-checkbox-by-updating.